# pass string parameter jni

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface, parameter-passing

I want to pass string as a parameter in with my jni. but when I pass the string; the received string is just a meaning less characters. In fact I cant pass my desired string from java to my C# function.

what should I do?

Edit :

jin.java:

```
public static native void myFunc( String name);
```

jin.cs:

```
public static void java_framewindow_myFunc(int env,int object,string name)
{
messagebox.show(name);
}
```

and I send string "Hi" from java, but the string shown in message box is meaningless.

Edit2:
here is my complete c# code :

```
using System;
using ObjectOrientedJNI; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
namespace CSharpInJava { 
    public class NativeJavaMethods { 

        static void Java_FrameWindow_myFunc(int env, int obj, string name){
           messagebox.show(name);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my complete java code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
public class FrameWindow extends Canvas { 
    int ref = 0;
      //Called by JVM to create Canvas' Peer 
    public void buttom_clicked() { 
        myFunc("hi"); 
    }
     native int myFunc(String name);
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Please provide source + values in debugger.

Comment: @user643540 I added the codes

Comment: Please provide the missing JNI code which glues these two pieces of code together.

Comment: I don't know C#, but it is good to know that Java stores string internally in UTF-16.

Comment: @houman001 tnx for your comment but I know that and in c++ and c we could use GetStringChars function but what should we do in c# to get that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used JNI with C#, but with C/C++ your native code should receive a [jstring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp428) type, instead of string as follows:

`static void Java_FrameWindow_myFunc(int env, int obj, jstring name)`

Typically, JNI documentation is poor (even more so with C# it seems) so turning to the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) is a good idea. Note that JNI uses modified UTF-8 strings.

### EDIT:

EJP is correct, your whole signature is incorrect. See [Native Method Arguments in the JNI Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715) for more detail.

```
static void Java_FrameWindow_myFunc( 
     JNIEnv *env,        /* interface pointer */ 
     jobject obj,        /* "this" pointer */
     jstring s)          /* argument #1 */
```

Comment: Same applies to the 'object' parameter. It isn't an 'int': in fact it isn't even an object, it's a jclass, as the method is static. OP appears to have just made the signature up.